# Implementing Grey World in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I am trying to implement Grey World algorithm in Javascript. I am going to use third party library like fabric.js. But all I need to know about this algorithm.

After gone through google I got [Link1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44692-3_42), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_normalization) and Using [CPP](http://opencvintro.blogspot.in/2015/05/grey-world-algorithm-in-opencv.html). But I am not clear about this algorithm. If I got this with an example then I am sure I can implement that.

Could anyone please give some details with an example, It will be very helpful for me.